# How to get specific values from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, find

So I am getting some data of a spreadsheet using gspread and they all go into a list. But I would like to just get the second, third and fourth value of that list separately.

Is there any way I can do this is python 3?
The lists look like this:

```
 ['22-6-2020 15:54:53', '4', '5', '46'],
 ['22-6-2020 15:54:53', '5', '3', '67'],
 ['22-6-2020 15:54:53', '1', '7', '5'],
 ['22-6-2020 15:54:53', '3', '86', '67'],
 ['22-6-2020 15:54:53', '1', '26', '12']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do so using list comprehension

```
data = [['22-6-2020 15:54:53', '4', '5', '46'],
 ['22-6-2020 15:54:53', '5', '3', '67'],
 ['22-6-2020 15:54:53', '1', '7', '5'],
 ['22-6-2020 15:54:53', '3', '86', '67'],
 ['22-6-2020 15:54:53', '1', '26', '12']]

l1, l2, l3 = [[d[x] for d in data] for x in range(1,4)]
print(l1, l2, l3)

#prints
['4', '5', '1', '3', '1'] ['5', '3', '7', '86', '26'] ['46', '67', '5', '67', '12']
```

Comment: thanks but I meant like every second from every list collected in their own list. The same for the third and fourth.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to do so, its slightly more complex due to nesting of list comprehension.

Comment: thanks a lot works like a charm! Could you explain what happens here? I would like to understand it.